# Data Binding in a WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, data-binding, user-controls

A seemingly simple problem that has me gridlocked. I have a usercontrol that contains a TextBlock.
I wish to bind several properties of the TextBlock (Text, FontSize, Foreground, Background, Margin). Rather than create a huge spaghetti of code and 5 DependencyProperties, I was thinking, the simple thing to do would be to create a small class for these properties and simply Register that.

Here's what I have in the UserControl.xaml

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" DataContext="XTitle"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=MultiButton, Path=XTitle.Text, FallbackValue='Heart-Rate'}" 
                   FontSize="{Binding ElementName=MultiButton, Path=XTitle.FontSize, FallbackValue='26'}" 
                   Foreground="{Binding ElementName=MultiButton, Path=XTitle.ForeColor, FallbackValue='White'}" 
                   Background="{Binding ElementName=MultiButton, Path=XTitle.Background, FallbackValue='Black'}" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

In the code behind (userControl.xaml.vb) I have this:

```
    Public Shared ReadOnly XTitleProperty As DependencyProperty

    Shared Sub New()
        XTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("XTitle", GetType(TextPart), GetType(MultiButton))
    End Sub

    Public Property XTitle As TextPart
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(XTitleProperty), TextPart)
        End Get
        Set(value As TextPart)
            SetValue(XTitleProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class TextPart
        Property Text As String = "ABCD"
        Property FontSize As Single = 16
        Property Foreground As Color = Colors.Yellow
        Property Background As Color = Colors.Black
    End Class
```

In the Window.xaml (and I'm just trying to get this all to work, hence no MVVM for now):

```
<Grid>
    <lbUserControl:MultiButton XTitle="{Binding SensorTitle}"/>
</Grid>
```

and finally in the Window.xaml.vb code-behind we have this:

```
    Private _sensorTitle As MultiButton.TextPart

    Public ReadOnly Property SensorTitle() As MultiButton.TextPart
        Get
            Return _sensorTitle
        End Get

    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _sensorTitle = New MultiButton.TextPart
        _sensorTitle.Text = "HRM"
        _sensorTitle.FontSize = 16
        _sensorTitle.Foreground = Colors.Cyan
        _sensorTitle.Background = Colors.SaddleBrown
    End Sub
```

I'm obviously missing a trick somewhere as I don't think the databinding is engaging at all. Happy to receive comments in either vb or c#. Thanks.

Comment: who is the source in your case. it should the be the owner datacontext.

Comment: Could you expand your comment? I'm not following you...

Comment: An easier approach would be to create a View-model with these properties and set it as data-context for the text block